# Does Nehemiah 6:10-12 contradict situation ethics?

Tags: ethics, law, temple, nehemiah

In Nehemiah 6:10-14, Shemaiah tries to get Nehemiah to meet with him in the temple and close the door, alleging (falsely) that people will try to kill Nehemiah at night otherwise. The goal was to get Nehemiah to sin, but Nehemiah refused, saying that someone like himself could never go to the temple to save his life.

Would this contradict situation ethics? If Nehemiah followed situation ethics, wouldn't entering the temple to save his life been permissible?

Comment: A brief definition of what situation ethics are would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

*Wikipedia* defines [Situational ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situational_ethics) as follows (emphasis mine):

> **Situational ethics** or **situation ethics** takes into account only the particular context of an act when evaluating it ethically, rather than judging it only according to absolute moral standards. With the intent to have a fair basis for judgments or action, **one looks to personal ideals of what is appropriate to guide them, rather than an unchanging universal code of conduct**, such as Biblical law under divine command theory or the Kantian categorical imperative. ...
>
> ...
>
> Fletcher, who became prominently associated with this approach in the English-speaking world due to his book (*Situation Ethics*), stated that "all laws and rules and principles and ideals and norms, are only contingent, only valid if they happen to serve love" **in the particular situation, and thus may be broken or ignored if another course of action would achieve a more loving outcome**. Fletcher has sometimes been identified as the founder of situation ethics, but he himself refers his readers to the active debate over the theme that preceded his own work.

If we imagine Nehemiah practicing situational ethics, we must first understand ***his* personal ideals**, and secondly ask what Nehemiah would consider a **more loving outcome**.

From what we read in Ezra-Nehemiah, one of his personal ideals is restoration of the temple so the people of Israel can once again worship God ***truly***.  If that's his ideal, then he wouldn't sacrilege the holiness of the temple by going inside for saving his life knowing that God *might* had planned to save him by other means.  Trusting God is not counter to situational ethics !

Secondly, even before the situation in Neh 6:10-14, Nehemiah was *already* **risking his life** for his project, which in turn (we can safely speculate) was done out of his love for God. This time is no different, the loving outcome is to continue the fight and to continue setting a role model for his fellow Israelites, to boost their *morale*.  I think he would rather die than to risk compromising his goal, and I think this is out of his love for Israel and for God.

**Conclusion**: In following situational ethics (which in this case happens to be consistent with following the Torah), Nehemiah wouldn't permit himself to enter the temple.

You would need to come up with a better example that could pit situational ethics against OT ethics :-).  (I could think of a few examples from the OT, but I don't want to spoil the fun).